# limiting checkpoint size in spark

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I'm using structured streaming framework in spark to read from a Kafka topic and do some aggregations on it. Going through documentation, I've framed my final query to be something like this --

```scala
val query = aggResultsFromStream
  .writeStream
  .foreach(myFancyForeachWriter)
  .outputMode("update")
  .option("truncate", "false")
  .option("checkpointLocation", s"/some/location/in/hdfs/$myapp-data")
  .trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime(30.seconds))
  .start()
```

Everything works great. The only problem is that the size of `/some/location/in/hdfs/$myapp-data` is just going on increasing. I was under the impression that it stores some information to recover from failure but I have a feeling it's just storing *everything*. So, is there

- some setting to purge older checkpoint data?
- or to do checkpointing a little less frequently? (less desirable)
- or checkpoint only metadata or kafka offsets to replay and recover lost data

Any resource or documentation talking about the above cases or a concrete example would be very very useful. thanks a lot!